# Proguard + Android Annotations: Can't find superclass or interface javac.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor

Tags: android, annotations, obfuscation, proguard, android-annotations

So some people have told me that with Android Studio and the newest version of the Android SDK I should be able to run Proguard on my project, which uses Android Annotations, with no problems. However, I've been struggling with this for many days now.

When I try to run Proguard via the Build->Generate Signed APK tool in Android Studio, I get hundreds of errors of the form:

```
com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotationprocessor.AnnotatedAbstractProcessor: can't find superclass or interface javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor
com.googlecode.androidannotations.AndroidAnnotationProcessor: can't find referenced method 'void init(javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment)' in class com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotationprocessor.AnnotatedAbstractProcessor
```

I've tried with the built in proguard-android.txt file that comes with the sdk and also with a custom one I copied from Android Annotations, I believe:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

I've also tried via gradle on the command line with the same result. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably upgrade your version of Android Annotations. Recent versions make a distinction between

- `androidannotations-X.Y.jar`, for generating the code at compile-time, and
- `androidannotations-X.Y-api.jar`, to be put in the directory `libs`; containing the code needed at run-time.

This avoids adding classes to the application that depend on classes that are not present in the Android run-time. For instance, ProGuard tries to resolve the dependencies and complains about `com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotationprocessor.AnnotatedAbstractProcessor`, which depends on the missing `javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor`.

Side-note: recent versions of the Android SDK use `proguard-project.txt` instead of `proguard.cfg` (with the default configuration that you probably copied from the outdated wiki page of Android Annotations). If you update the line with `proguard.config` in `project.properties`, the build process automatically applies a default configuration. The file `proguard-project.txt` can then be empty to start with; it only needs to contain project-specific configuration.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I had the latest version of AA. My problem was that I had androidannotations-X.Y.jar listed as a dependency instead of androidannotations-X.Y.-api.jar.